# C - Logical AND operands not swapable in this case?

Tags: c

I am learning linked lists in C, and I came across an error I don't understand.  In the snippet of code I have pasted below, when I have while(a && b), I get an infinite loop, but when I run while(b && a), the program works.  I am new to C and don't understand why I get the infinite loop in the first case.

This gives me an infinite loop:

```
while((*searchNodePtr).data != dataValue && searchNodePtr != NULL) {
    prevNodePtr = searchNodePtr;
    searchNodePtr = (*searchNodePtr).next;  
}
```

But this works (swapped while condition operands):

```
while(searchNodePtr != NULL && (*searchNodePtr).data != dataValue) {
    prevNodePtr = searchNodePtr;
    searchNodePtr = (*searchNodePtr).next;  
}
```

Any clarification would be much appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is due to [short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation). In the first `while` you dereference a `NULL`-pointer (undefined behaviour) when `searchNodePtr` is `NULL` because the check for `NULL` only happens after that.

Whereas in the second `while` when the first operand of the `&&` is false, the second doesn't get evaluated. So when `searchNodePtr` is `NULL` the expression `(*searchNodePtr).data` is not evaluated and you don't dereference the `NULL`-pointer.

Answer (score 2):

C uses short circuit evaluation in logical expressions (operator `&&`, operator `||`, etc).

In a expression `a && b`, `b` will only be evaluated if `a` is true (non-zero).   This is because, if `a` is false (zero) then no value of `b` will make the expression `a && b` give a true result.

As to your specific case `(*searchNodePtr).data` is only a valid expression if `searchNodePtr` points at a valid object (and is not `NULL`).   Otherwise it gives undefined behaviour.

So, your first case is assuming `searchNodePtr` is non-NULL, dereferencing it (giving undefined behaviour which means all bets are off if `searchNodePtr` is actually NULL), and THEN testing if `searchNodePtr` is NULL.

The second case is checking that `searchNodePtr` is not NULL, and then evaluating `(*searchNodePtr).data` and testing if it is true (non-zero).   This is the right way of doing such things.

Incidentally, `(*searchNodePtr).data` is more readably expressed as `searchNodePtr->data`.    But you should still test `searchNodePtr` is non-NULL.